# How delete all symbols from string except letters and numbers?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying use next code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[\\p{L}[0-9]]+|-" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

but it doesn't work. I use different variations of this, but without success too.

Example text:

```
Это тестовый.!!?! ;$%#@@@## (вопрос) номер 1256 - верно.
```

Example output:

```
Это тестовый вопрос номер 1256 - верно
```

Comment: If you need to delete all chars except letters and digits use `@"[^\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9]+"`. If you need to also keep hyphens, keep the `-` at the end of the character class. Could you please share a comprehensive test case?

Comment: But If I want to get only letters and numbers, what I should to use?

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/dvUxdp. `%Text-1();` => `Text1` with `@"[^\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9]+"` regex. Is that what you need?

Comment: Could you please share an example input and expected output? It is necessary to provide a trustworthy answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sure.
Input: `Это тестовый.!!?! ;$%#@@@## (вопрос) номер 1256 - верно.`
Output: `Это тестовый вопрос номер 1256 - верно`

It's cyrillic alphabet. So when you provide answer, I marked it's right surely. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer with the adjusted regex and a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is actually matching characters you want to remove, but it is corrupt and does not even do that (due to a "wild" `]`).

If you need to delete all chars except letters, digits, hyphens and whitespaces, use `@"[^\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9\\s-]+"`.

**Details**:

- `[^\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9\\s-]+` - one or more characters that are NOT:

  - `\\p{L}` - Unicode letters
  - `\\p{M}` - diacritics
  - `0-9` - ASCII digits
  - `\\s` - whitespace
  - `-` - a literal hyphen.

See the online [Objective-C demo](https://ideone.com/yilxRh):

```
NSString *text = @"Это тестовый.!!?! ;$%#@@@## (вопрос) номер 1256 - верно";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9\\s-]+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *result = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(result);
```

Result: `Это тестовый  вопрос номер 1256 - верно`

Comment: It's perfect and brilliant answer with the best traditions of S.O. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

1st find the num-alphabet set:

```
NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
```

2nd get the invert set of it, and we will use it as separators:

```
NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [alphaSet invertedSet];
```

3nd use separator to separate the old string and then join characters back together with @"":

```
NSString *newString = [[oldString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: separatorSet]componentsJoinedByString:@""];'
```